# Change default hosting firebase with AWS

Tags: firebase, amazon-route53, firebase-hosting

I am using firebase hosting, but I want to change the url so I have created a domain with amazon (route 53) and it's approved. 
I created in Route 53 a new register with the value and TXT type that firebase returns me but It still doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Thank you,

Comment: We can't see what precisely you've done, so it's going to be hard to help right now. Where are you stuck? Is the Firebase console not picking up your TXT record? If so, how long did you wait? Also: show what you've done in the Route 53 DNS, since the problem is likely there. A quick way to check is `dig -t txt +noall +answer karosdomain.com`, which is similar to what Firebase Hosting does to check our records.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I have done is :1) to enter in hosting of firebase and I add the new dns created with Route 53. 2) I continued until the end 3) I entered in example.firebaseapp.com and I see my web 4) I write the example.com and I can't see my web.   I supposed that adding this dns in firebase I will use my web, but will appear the new url

Comment: I have to use the advance configuration in firebase or wait 24h?. Sorry for the question, I don't know very well about this

Answer (score 3):

I too have my domain managed by AWS using Route 53 DNS editor. I also wanted to host my demo app on firebase (using a `demo.example.com` subdomain) before I host the production app on AWS.

These are the steps I took;

1. Created a new project on Firebase.
2. On Firebase, I went to hosting and on the domain field I wrote `demo.example.com` as this is the subdomain I wanted to host my app on.
3. Firebase gave me the TXT records to verify my domain, I added the TXT record on AWS Route 53 on my domain name `example.com` and the value provided by Firebase.
4. After the TXT records got verified (took 10 - 15 mins). I then created the subdomains, `demo.example.com` on AWS Route 53 and pointing to two of Firebase IP address on Route 53 value field (**each IP on its own line**) then create the route on Route 53 and click Finish on Firebase then wait for a few hours or so (may take up to 24 of them).

To everyone wishing to mix up their food and some time, technologies, you are not alone!

Comment: Where did you get the Firebase IP address ?
Could you please provide an example of how did you route your subdomain to firebase?

Comment: @GeorgeAlex can you explain to me what is not clear from the instructions above so I can elaborate clearly?

Comment: finally I figured out how to do the above steps. However, I have at least  one concern.
I have a mobile app that uses firebase as backend.  The domain with the presentation page is hosted by aws. In my app, I have a function that implies account password reset.  Firebase provides an email template that can be configured, so that in order to reset the password, the user should access something like https://app.example.com/?mode=action&oobCode=code.
At the moment it seems firebase is connected to my aws domain, but I don't know if I should do something additional.

Comment: At the moment the link from the template: app.example.com/?mode=action&oobCode=code is working, but the domain verification failed. 
Currently, the email is sent from noreply@project-name.firebaseapp.com and I would like to be sent from noreply@app.example.com.
Are there additional configurations that must be accomplished?